# What does :: indicate in all-quantifier predicates?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, notation

Can somebody explain to me the meaning of $::$ in the following predicate?

$$(\forall i : P(i) : Q(i)) \equiv (\forall i :: P(i) \implies Q(i))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"::" is ":" followed by another ":", i.e., two separators.

"$\forall i :: P(i) \implies Q(i)$" is the same as  "$\forall i :    : P(i) \implies Q(i)$", i.e, there is no premise/second term. Or you can consider the second term as $\text{true}$ or $\top$.

This situation is similar to the slice notation for lists in Python. For a list `A`, all four notations `A[::3]`, `A[0::3]`, `A[:len(A):3]` and `A[0:len(A):3]` mean the same thing.